# MATLAB JA Builder

Tags: java, matlab, dll, matlab-java

When I run the program in Netbean, it shows the following message. What can I do to solve this problem?

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   Failed to find the library mclmcrrt7_17.dll, required by MATLAB
>   Builder JA, on java.library.path.

This library is typically installed along with MATLAB or the MCR, its absence may indicate an issue with that installation or the current path configuration.
The MCR version that this component is trying to use is: 7.17.

Answer (score 0):

For a MATLAB compiled program to run it needs MCR. The MATLAB version and MCR version need to match. Here are the MCR version and MATLAB version mappings.

---

MATLAB            | MCR

---

R14    (7.0)      | 7.0
 R14SP1 (7.0.1)    | 7.1
 R14SP2 (7.0.4)    | 7.2
 R14SP3 (7.1)      | 7.3
 R2006a (7.2)      | 7.4
 R2006b (7.3)      | 7.5
 R2007a (7.4)      | 7.6
 R2007b (7.5)      | 7.7
 R2008a (7.6)      | 7.8
 R2008b (7.7)      | 7.9
 R2009a (7.8)      | 7.10
 R2009b (7.9)      | 7.11
 R2010a (7.10)     | 7.13
 R2010b(7.11)      | 7.14
 R2011a (7.12)     | 7.15
 R2011b (7.13)     | 7.16
 R2012a (7.14)     | 7.17
 R2012b (8.0)      | 8.0
 R2013a (8.1)      | 8.1
 R2013b (8.2)      | 8.2
 R2014a (8.3)      | 8.3
 R2014b (8.4)      | 8.4

---

Please make sure that your program was build using R2012a. If not install the mapped version of MCR from the above table.

Also, you might have multiple MCR's installed. So either uninstall or remove (from environment path) the other versions of MCR just to make sure that it is picking the right one.